# Read long value from webservice using SoapClient

Tags: php, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm writing a soap consumer in PHP for a ws written in Java (Jax ws). The webservice exports a function *listRooms()* that returns an array of the complex data type *Room* which contains an id (64 bit long) and a description (string). Now whenever I consume the webservice using SoapClient, the id is converted to float (as there are no 64 bit integers in PHP) and I want to avoid it. As I will need the room id to consume other web services I would rather avoid this implicit conversion to float, keeping it in a string.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there any problem with it being a float?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This might help:](http://www.spinics.net/lists/phpsoap/msg02077.html)

> The long overflows because ext/soap maps it to an int, and you're on a 32bit arch. You can easily fix that problem by using a custom type mapper to override the internal handling of {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema }long:

```
function to_long_xml($longVal) {
  return '<long>' . $longVal . '</long>';
}
function from_long_xml($xmlFragmentString) {
  return (string)strip_tags($xmlFragmentString);
}
$client = new SoapClient('http://acme.com/products.wsdl', array(
  'typemap' => array(
    array(
      'type_ns' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
      'type_name' => 'long',
      'to_xml' => 'to_long_xml',
      'from_xml' => 'from_long_xml',
    ),
  ),
));
```

Also check to see exactly what you get back from the SOAP call, as per the manual [add 'trace' and use getLastRequest](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php):

```
<?php
$client = SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
$result = $client->SomeFunction();
echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: That's good! Personally I am stuck on SOAP 'multicall' right now, you'll be needing that too if that WSDL of yours is taking too long...

Comment: what's that? (I'm having also problems with the Java ws, for some functions the object returned is empty, do you have a solution also for that?)

Comment: Some API code is badly written ad you may be the first to be testing a particular call. Contact the developers if you get excessive delays or not the results you expect and develop a working relationship with them.

Comment: You just saved my life.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do it, is just using the `float()` function before the data to sent as a long type.

In the example below I'm use a stdclass object to sent as a parameter:

```
<?php
if ($index == "Your_longtype_Field"){
    $a->$index = (float) $value;
} else {
    $a->$index = $value;
}
?>
```