# It's not possible to get a long integer from a web service response

Tags: php, soap, long-integer

I use the `SoapClient` class for SOAP interactions. When a SOAP response contains long integer, PHP converts it to the scientific notation. How can I get such value and use it later in a SOAP request?

I can't use gmp, the value is cast to float before I can access it. `gmp_init(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type`

also see: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=100615

```
$wsld = 'http://example.com?wsdl';
$soap = new \SoapClient($wsld);
$result=$soap->foo();
echo $result->return->id; // echo 1.1122233344456E+14 instead of 111222333444555;
```

Comment: Please provide sufficient amount of code here - if the link happens to be broken the question will lack some portion of information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456615/how-to-convert-float-value-to-integer-in-php

Comment: @sitilge That question is not what I asked here. The original value (from remote server) is long int and I want prevent casting it to float.

Comment: There is no way how to change the response from the server upon identical requests.

Comment: You can try to overwrite the internal handling of long by using a custom type mapper, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6150928/2883067

Comment: Ugly as it would be, if the format conversion proves untenable and insurmountable, you could consider returning the value as a string and parsing it on the consuming end. Again, not pretty, but....

Comment: You may want to add the "PHP" tag to this question since that is the language being used by your web server.

Comment: @DavidW I can not modify the server.

Comment: @kfinto Thanks, however due to this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55348 I can't use that.

Comment: @PHPst Making of copy of the WSDL and changing the data type is not an option? You can still keep the same endpoint. Also have a look into typemap (it's an option with the SoapClient class).

Comment: @RicardoVelhote Thanks a lot. Changing the WSDL file works. Please add this as an answer.

Comment: You can make it a string, but than using an integer as a string is not a very  good idea.  You can also try with `echo number_format($result->return->id,0,null,'')`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can make a local copy of the WSDL and change the datatype of the field you are having trouble with to a string.

That has the disadvantage that you will have to track changes to the XML but it's the path of least resistance that will provide you a more immediate solution.

---

As an alternative, more robust in a way, looking at the [SoapClient documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) there is the *typemap* option that you can use.

> The typemap option is an array of type mappings. Type mapping is an array with keys type_name, type_ns (namespace URI), from_xml (callback accepting one string parameter) and to_xml (callback accepting one object parameter).

Perhaps this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150928/541884) might help you with using the *typemap*. Without knowing your schema it's hard to help you with source code but the example may be applicable to you.

Here is a verbatim copy of the source code posted in the answer above:

```
function to_long_xml($longVal) {
  return '<long>' . $longVal . '</long>';
}
function from_long_xml($xmlFragmentString) {
  return (string)strip_tags($xmlFragmentString);
}
$client = new SoapClient('http://acme.com/products.wsdl', array(
  'typemap' => array(
    array(
      'type_ns' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
      'type_name' => 'long',
      'to_xml' => 'to_long_xml',
      'from_xml' => 'from_long_xml',
    ),
  ),
));
```

Comment: Due to this bug bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55348 I can't use `typemap`

Comment: @PHPst I understand. It was just an alternative suggestion for people that might not encounter that bug. The original suggestion I made in the comment is still there ;)